# Automaticaly commit when updating pacemaker configuration

Tags: linux, automation, pacemaker, corosync

I'm trying to automate the administration of my servers which are running corosync/pacemaker. For that I generate a file containing the modifs that needs to be applied to the configuration. To apply this file I usualy do :

```
crm configure load update path_to_file
```

It works fine when I do it myself. But whenever there is a warning generated by the config, crm ask if I really want's to commit the changes. As far as I'm trying to automate this task I'd like to get rid of this question and directly commit the changes. Is-it possible ?

Comment: If crm does not have a force or -y flag or something , check out expect and autoexpect as that might be an option, should all else fail.

Comment: Indeed there is a force option : -F, and it did the tricks. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-F` force flag to override the prompting from `crm`.